# In CKAN, is it possible to override templates of customized extensions?

Tags: jinja2, ckan

I created a CKAN extension for blog. The blog extension overrides ckan core template files and working fine.

Then I created another extension called ui, to create a new template for ckan. In this new extension can I override my blog extension's template files?

For example: if I have 'blog/templates/blog_post.htm' in blog extension, can I override it in ui extension by '/ui/templates/blog_post.htm'

This way I can keep my extension working with ckan template and it working with my new templates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can override template from other extensions. You just need to be careful with the order in which you load the plugins in your ini file (the one overriding the templates should be loaded first).

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I been pulling what little strands of hair out that I had.